# listview properties are not available

Tags: vba, excel, listview

I pass a listview to a custom sub and some of the listview properties are not available within the called sub, e.g. .name, .width, and a few more.
 
Checking the input listview in the called sub, all properties are visible in the watch window. Trying to change any of these missing ones errors (both from within app or immediate window). 
In the calling sub all properties are available and can be changed. 
Strange is that object browser displays only the reduced set for Listview4.
The object itself is created with the built-in form designer, type is Listview4. 
Applies to Excel 2013 Prof on W7 and W10.

SOLVED: By declaring the type of input parameter as Object instead of Listivew (Listview4), everything works fine. It is still strange that Listview can have different properties within the same form.

Comment: Welcome!  You'll need to share a lot more information that that, including but not limited to, the subs, properties, errors, listviews and objects you mentioned, and what you have have, what you tried, what your *specific* problem is, and what you need in the end.  Please check out the [tour], ask well as [ask] and special attention to [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: By declaring the type of input parameter as Object instead of Listivew (Listview4), everything works fine. It is still strange that Listview can have different properties within the same form.